# Exclude Broadcast Receiver from Recent Application List/Task Manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, taskmanager

I have a semi-successful app on the market that uses broadcast receivers for a few of its features. As a request from many of the users, I have successfully excluded a few activities from the "Recent Applications List" by adding this line to the activities in the manifest:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

I am trying to do the same thing with my broadcast receiver. I have tried adding that line to my receiver and all of the dependant activities to no avail. What can I do to "hide" the broadcast receiver from the user? Is this supposed to work, or is there an alternative?

Also, how do I stop the app from showing in the task manager (running application list) when a broadcast is received? There are quite a few apps on my phone (my app included) that show up in my 3rd party task manager that do not show as running applications in the default settings->apps->running list. Can somebody please explain why this is the case, and what I can possibly do to keep it off the task manager list as well (without knowing how the each individual task manager searches for apps)?

Thanks!

NOTE: I use the word "hide" apprehensively. It is basically to de-clutter the recent applications list as requested by the users. No ill intents :D.

Comment: A pure BroadcastReceiver will not be displayed in the recent apps list. How do you implemented the receiver to get such a result? I mean I see only the app in the list, not each separate activity...

Comment: Just a short check on my side: If you have multiple entry points defined in your manifest, each of these are displayed in the applications list, but again: I have no clue how you managed to get a BroadcastReceiver in the list...

Comment: I may not have described my problem clearly. While you are correct that only the application shows in the list (not each individual activity), if all activities are excluded from the list in the manifest, then the app should not show up. In my case, all my activites are excluded, but when my app receives a broadcast, the application still shows in the list. This is my issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use a service which handles the broadcast?

Comment: I have not...I do not wish to have a service which is always running in the background. I would like the app as lightweight as possible.

Comment: a service does not need to run always in the background. You have control over the service and you decide when you should kill himself.

Comment: I need the receiver to always be active, hence the service would have to be as well

Comment: You do know that you can register a receiver in the manifest which will always react if something triggers his intent filter? You should check the possible usages of a broadcast receiver... seriously

Comment: I didnt mean "as well", I meant that if I removed the receiver, the service would have to be running at all times. And I'm aware how receivers work...I've been programming android for well over 2 years. My receiver reacts every time the intent is received...I am just simply looking for a way for the application not to show up on the recent applications list when this occurs.

Comment: `if all activities are excluded from the list in the manifest` Then your app won't work on 3.1 and above. The user must manually open your app at least once before it is eligible to receive broadcasts and intents ([source](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols))

Comment: @RaghavSood That is very interesting, but that doesn't seem to be the behaviour my app is portraying. The receiver always works when the intent is received, whether or not the app was just killed. This works even on 4.2. Either way, that is not my issue...my issue has to do with excluding the application from the list of recent apps when a broadcast is received, not the receiving of said broadcasts.

Comment: Ok forget the service. If you create a simple broadcastreceiver that is defined in the manifest, it will always react (at least when the app was started once). So it receives something, does something and done. It should then never ever appear on the recent apps list, at least afaik. So what are you doing within your broadcast? That must be the reason that your app is listed there? I mean otherwise all the "ON_BOOT_COMPLETE" receiver would be in the list right after booting up the device. So: What are you doing in your receiver? Give us some code...

Comment: For testing purposes, I had commented everything out and only showed a toast. It still shows up.

Comment: What are the intent filters/broadcasts you are listening for?

Comment: just ACTION_USER_PRESENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive the broadcast start/launch the new activity/service with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`. It's hard to tell without the source code, but you may also want to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`.

Comment: Although this didn't really answer the question, as you are the only one to actually post an answer, I am awarding you the bounty. Unfortunately for me, SO does not allow me to get my bounty back if there are no sufficient answers, so it's better that you get the bounty than it disappearing into the ether.

Comment: Considering you did provide SOME help, I'd say yes. Morally, atleast,